# Profile is null while trying to get a profile by id

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

i am trying to render a single profile by id but my console returns `profile is null`

This is my Profile.js:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import ProfileTop from './ProfileTop';
import ProfileAbout from './ProfileAbout';
import ProfileExperience from './ProfileExperience';
import ProfileEducation from './ProfileEducation';
import ProfileGithub from './ProfileGithub';
import { getProfileById } from '../../actions/profile';

const Profile = ({ getProfileById, profile: { profile }, auth }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  useEffect(() => {
    getProfileById(id);
  }, [getProfileById, id]);

  return (
    <section className="container">
       
        <Fragment>
          <Link to="/profiles" className="btn btn-light">
            Back To Profiles
          </Link>
        </Fragment>
        {auth.isAuthenticated &&
            auth.loading === false &&
            auth.user._id === profile.user._id && (
              <Link to="/edit-profile" className="btn btn-dark">
                Edit Profile
              </Link>
            )}
    </section>
  );
};

Profile.propTypes = {
  getProfileById: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  profile: state.profile,
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProfileById })(Profile);
```

And this is my profile `getProfileById` action where i fetch the data from my API:

```
// Get profile by ID
export const getProfileById = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/profile/user/${userId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROFILE,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: PROFILE_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

So i managed to find out that the error is coming from the following block of code inside the Profile.js

```
              {auth.isAuthenticated &&
                auth.loading === false &&
                auth.user._id === profile.user._id && (
                  <Link to="/edit-profile" className="btn btn-dark">
                    Edit Profile
                  </Link>
                )}
```

So if i comment the above block of code my action GET_PROFILE is being dispatch with all my user´s  data but if i do not comment it i get `profile is null`

This is my router for getting a profile by user_id:

```
router.get('/user/:user_id', checkObjectId('user_id'), async ({ params: { user_id } }, res) => {
      try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({
          user: user_id
        }).populate('user', ['name', 'avatar']);
  
        if (!profile) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Profile not found' });
  
        return res.json(profile);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server error' });
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Focus on this: `TypeError: err.response is undefined`.  This means that you are in the `catch (err)` block of `getProfileById`.  You need to: 1) figure out why your API call is throwing an error 2) fix your catch block to work with various types of errors, which won't all have the properties that you are accessing.

Comment: @LindaPaiste i´d identified where the error is coming from but i cannot tell why this is happening do you know what am i doing wrong? I edited my question

Comment: The relevant code is not in the question. The error is not related to either react nor redux but instead your api that's running on localhost:5000

Comment: @geisterfurz007 how can you tell? i´ll paste my route for getting profile by user_id

Comment: Did you try the API with postman?

Comment: @Minsaf yes and in postman i works perfectly fine. I pass the user id and it brings the profile of that user, also in my app it works fine, get my action GET_PROFILE in my redux dev tools with all the payload with the data, that´s why i am saying that is when i check for my user auth and if both ids are the same that generates the error `profile is null`

Comment: I think you’re getting a different error than before?  You may have fixed the backend error.  Now the problem is in your conditional rendering.  The profile variable will be null/undefined on the first render and until the fetch has completed.  Add in an && profile before you check that the ids match.  Otherwise you may have problems with accessing properties on an object that doesn’t exist.